# App crashes when email or password are wrong with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

so I'm using the latest versions of **react native**, **firebase** + **react-native-form-validator**.
when I try to log in with an existing user with the right email and password everything is great, but, when I insert wrong email or password the app crashes and I get this error:

[image: c.call is not a function]

the relevant lines of code are:

```js
    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false }

    userLogin = () => {
            this.setState({ loading: true });

            this.validate({
                email: { required: true, email: true },
                password: { required: true, minlength: 5 }
            });

            if (this.isFormValid()) {
                firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then(() => Actions.partyzmain())
                .catch(setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({ error: 'Email or password are inccorect!', password: '', loading: false });
                }, 5000));                 
            }
            else {
                if (this.isFieldInError('password')) {
                    this.setState({ error: 'Wrong password!', password: '', loading: false });
                }
                if (this.isFieldInError('email')) {
                    this.setState({ error: 'Invalid email adress!', loading: false });
                }
            }
    };
```

I set a .catch error and I really don't understand why isn't it working properly.

many thanks to the answers.

Comment: auth.js line 17 and etc. try to find place where call being called\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct.

Only possible issue may be `setTimeout` that runs `this.setState` in different scope as I see in error screen which shows backtrace with timers.

I recommend You to use `async/await` and handle all throwables using `try...catch` construction.

For timers You can use such method:

```
const wait = (timer) => 
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timer);
  })
```

and overall code is:

```
state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false }


userLogin = async () => {
  try {
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        this.validate({
            email: { required: true, email: true },
            password: { required: true, minlength: 5 }
        });

        if (!this.isFormValid()) {
            if (this.isFieldInError('password')) {
                this.setState({ 
                  error: 'Wrong password!', 
                  password: '', loading: false 
                });
            }

            if (this.isFieldInError('email')) {
                this.setState({ 
                  error: 'Invalid email address!', 
                  loading: false 
                });
            }
            return;
        }

        await firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  this.state.email, 
                  this.state.password
                );
        Actions.partyzmain();
  }
  catch (error) {
      console.debug(error);

      if (error.code.startsWith('auth')) {
        await wait(1000);
        this.setState({ 
          error: 'Email or password are inccorect!', 
          password: '', 
          loading: false 
        });
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: It says "there is no user record corresponding to this identifier. the user may have been deleted."

Comment: @AdarWallerstein change `console.error` in my answer to `console.debug` otherwise will show red screen :)